# Best way to administer a website remotely

Tags: web-server, remote

I have a Windows computer running an intranet website with IIS and I was wondering what the best way was to administer it from another computer, in this case, a Mac.

What I want to do:

1. Be able to edit pages from my Mac.
2. <s>VNC into the server because it is 'headless'</s>. (Already have this set up)

My current file syncing setup: 
I have [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com) setup to sync files between the computers and then use PureSync to sync the files in the Dropbox folder into the `wwwroot` folder.

Is there a better (faster/easier) way I could do all this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming both machines are on the same LAN.  If so, why not just share out the `wwwroot` folder and mount it from the Mac's Finder?

To share out a folder in Windows XP, you can use the Simple Filesharing, but I usually turn it off to give me more flexibility.

1. Browse to C:\inetpub (or wherever your IIS webroot is, but that's the default) in My Computer.  Go to Tools > Folder Options > View tab and near the bottom, uncheck "Use Simple File Sharing".
2. Now right-click on the wwwroot folder and choose "Sharing and Security..." and under the sharing tab, add Everyone with Full Control (or you can add a specific domain user and/or create a new local user if you want, but you'll need to grant that user Modify permissions under the Security settings for the wwwroot folder if it's not the local administrator account on the XP machine).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about Windows but how do you share it?

Comment: Depends on the version of Windows (XP Home, XP Pro, Windows 7, etc.).  What version is it?

Comment: XP Professional.

Comment: Right click the folder, go to properties, then go to the sharing tab.